# Interstaff distance in Musixtex

Tags: musixtex

It is needed to adjust the interstaff distance, the basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{musixtex} 

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.75\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\centering
%\resizebox{0.46\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{adjustbox}{width=.6\textwidth,center}
\begin{music}
    \parindent3mm
    \instrumentnumber{2}
    \setstaffs1{1}
    \setstaffs2{1}
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \setclef1\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 1
    \setclef2\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 2
    \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}4} %Compás en 4/4
    \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
    \Notes \sk\hl j & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*}\en\setdoublebar
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{3}{4}}\changecontext
    \notes \sk\hlp j & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*}\en\setdoublebar
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}{4}}\changecontext
    \notes \sk\wh j & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*}\en
    \setdoubleBAR
    \endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
\end{music}
\end{adjustbox}
%}

\end{document}
```

The current output:
[image: current]

The expected output (note that is needed more space between staffs):
[image: expected]

Comment: Please study page 106 of the MusixTex manual.

Comment: Solved: \setinterstaff{1}{20}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{musixtex} 

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.75\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\centering
%\resizebox{0.46\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{adjustbox}{width=.6\textwidth,center}
\begin{music}
    \parindent3mm
    \instrumentnumber{2}
    \setstaffs1{1}
    \setstaffs2{1}
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \setclef1\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 1
    \setclef2\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 2
    \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}4} %Compás en 4/4
    \setinterstaff{1}{20}%Distancia entre sistemas del pentagrama
    \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
    \Notes \sk\hl j & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*}\en\setdoublebar
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{3}{4}}\changecontext
    \notes \sk\hlp j & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*}\en\setdoublebar
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}{4}}\changecontext
    \notes \sk\wh j & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*}\en
    \setdoubleBAR
    \endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
\end{music}
\end{adjustbox}
%}

\end{document}
```

The output is as follow:
[image: solved]